# Linear algebra, common points between 3 planes

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all the common points between the planes 
x+2y+z=1,
2x+4y+z=3
andx+2y+3z=−1

can you guys explain all steps im so stupid in linear thank you

Comment: It is not really a good way to ask an answer. Take a look here and improve it. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2790641/linear-algebra-common-points-between-3-planes

Comment: @gimusi The link you provided comes back to this very page.

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question
And for help with formatting.
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

This is the non homogeneous linear system
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 1  \\
2 & 4 & 1  \\
1 & 2 & 3 
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
3 \\
-1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which can be written as
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 4 & 1 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & -1
\end{array}
\right]
$$
and solved by Gauss elimination. Subtracting two times the first from the second row and subtracting the first from the third row gives
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & -2
\end{array}
\right]
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$
And this means
$$
x + 2 y = 2 \\
z = -1
$$
which is the line
$$
L = \{ (x, -(1/2) x + 1, -1) \mid x \in \mathbb{R} \}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the augmented matrix of the linear system  and pˆroced with Gauß elimination to obtain the rediced row d=reduction form of the matrix of the left-hand side:
\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc|r}
1&2&1&1\\ 2&4&1&3\\ 1&2&3&-1
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc|rc}
1&2&1&1\\ 0&0&-1&1\\ 0&0&2&-2
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc|rc}
1&2&1&1\\ 0&0&-1&1\\ 0&0&0&0
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}\\[1ex]
\rightsquigarrow&\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc|rc}
1&2&0&2\\ 0&0&1&-1\\ 0&0&0&0
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

So the solutions are an affine subspace of dimension $1$ ( a line):
$$x+2y=2,\quad z=-1$$
or, in vector form, setting $y=t$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\-1
\end{bmatrix}+t  \begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\0
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: thank you for the answer but can you explain the last step since you assumed y=t? I didn't get it...

Comment: It is just a change in the notation, to have a neutral parameter. Actually, $z$ is independent of $y$, and $x$ can be expressed in function of $y$, so the parametrisation of the line is $x=2-2y=2-2t,\; y=t,\; z=-1$. Is it clearer?

Comment: Now its super clear, thank you so much :)